# How can i uninstall a plugin in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, findbugs

I have installed findbug, but it is not visible in my project explorer when I right click and check. I would like to reinstall the plugin again and check, but I do not see an option to uninstall the plugin.

How can i uninstall the plugin?
Im using Eclipse Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)

Comment: `Help` -> `About Eclipse` -> `Installation Details`.

Comment: @AleksandrM: Even if so short, it's nevertheless a correct answer for the question, so why commenting?

Comment: @Geziefer: The comment box was closer than answer section. :)

Comment: Are you sure it's not there? I can never find it because it seems to be in an illogical location in the menu (above **Refresh** and **Close Project**). Does it show in the project properties?

Comment: Yes it is not there.As mentioned by Jatin, in Luna version, About Eclipse-->Installation details-->Shows the installed software. But my initial problem still persists that, findbug is not visible at all even after reinstalling the plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove the ADT plugin from Eclipse is to go to Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details.
Select a plug-in you want to uninstall, then click Uninstall... button at the bottom.

For more detail visit http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks now i can uninstall. But even if i reinstalled that findbug is not visible :(

Comment: It's moved in Neon to Eclipse > About Eclipse > Installation Details. You also have to search in Installed Software, not Plug-ins, to remove it (even though it's listed in both places).